# Place tick label inside in a Plotly Dash chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am facing an issue of placing a categorical tick labels inside the chart in my Plotly Dash environment.

Here is the app:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px


animals = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
fig = px.bar(x=[20, 14, 23], y=animals)
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'ticklabelposition': 'inside'})
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 50])

chart_bar = dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport",
                            "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(children=chart_bar, md=6)],
        className='app-body')
        ],
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and here is the result
[image: a chart produced be Dash App]

Seems like *yaxis={'ticklabelposition': 'inside'}* is not working

If I do the same chart **outside** of the app it is working just fine. Here, produced by exactly the same script.

[image: Desired result]

Seems like some of the Plotly parameters are not working inside the Dash app. Or I am wrong?
What did I missed? Is there a way to place the labels inside, on the bars?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug for some versions of Plotly. I'm running your exact code for Plotly versions  `5.1.0` and `5.2.2`, and getting these results in the Dash app:

**Plot 1** - `Plotly 5.1.0`:

[image]

**Plot 2** `Plotly 5.2.2`:

[image]

However, I'm ***not*** getting `Plot 1` when running the same code outside of Dash. So I suspect the cause is a mix of versions between Dash and Plotly.

Please provide info about your versions if further investigation is needed. Just run:

```
import dash
import plotly

print(dash.__version__)
print(plotly.__version__)
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you. I am running Dash 1.13.4 and Plotly 4.14.3

Comment: @Anton Interesting indeed. Please consider trying both `5.1.0` and `5.2.2` and see if we're getting matching results wrt Dash vs only Plotly.

Comment: I'll try and check. Thank you!

Comment: So in my case: Plotly 5.1.0 - it was working properly without Dash and **didn't work in Dash**
Plotly 5.2.1 - the same - it was working properly without Dash and **didn't work in Dash**
finally I updated Dash to the version 1.21.0 - it starter to work as expected in both settings (inside Dash and outside)